# thinkpad sl400c laptop not booting up

Tags: windows-7, boot

I run win 7, i recently connected three seagate external hdd to it and was copying some data, unfortunately one of them disconnected and they system hung up, i took out the battery and tried to boot up the laptop again, but it never did. it just shows the thinkpad splash screen and then the cursor starts blinking and then it tries to boot from the start again. I can however access the disks via an ubuntu live CD. I also tried pressing f8 to reach the startup repair menu, but I cannot get to that screen. Is there a way I can fix this problem without formatting the system as i do not possess the win 7 disk?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems that you have lost or broken the MBR,

I'll leave a links to help with this.

For getting a win7 repair disc, and can follow these simple steps:

[Windows 7 - MBR - Restore Windows 7 Master Boot Record](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html)

If you want to operate from ubuntu could follow these steps:

[Win Boot-Repair from Ubuntu.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: i tried the boot repair from ubuntu but it did not work. the pastebin file was http://paste.ubuntu.com/1545848/

Comment: Your MBR seems fine, if you are sure that you can not access the menu `F8` & `F10`, chances are your boot order in your bios has changed, should be able to access to Lenovo bios menu by pressing `F1` on startup, in any case if proper  reconfigure your BIOS boot sequence fails, you can use the tools ["**Lenovo bios update**"](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS004224), which will add functionality in addition to put order in your system startup.

Comment: well, a system format worked. thnx for the help.